# wpf open multiple / duplicate of the same window

Tags: c#, wpf, duplicates, window, multiple-instances

Hoping you can help on this one as I am getting a little stuck. I am new and learning C# / WPF Language and by doing so have decided to create an application. The application itself works, but for functionality I need to make a slight change.

The application consists of 3 windows (Settings, Control Panel, Display Screen). The Control Panel is designed so that on clicks it updates labels / textboxes etc on the Display Screen. This works perfectly fine. However my issue was when I decided to open a 2nd Display Screen (a duplicate of the first).

This is what I have at the minute:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Controller.xaml
/// </summary>
    public partial class Controller : Window
    {
        MainWindow bWin = new MainWindow();
        public Controller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bWin.Show();
        }

        private void btnNewScreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bWin.Show();
        }
```

The btnNewScreen does not open a 2nd instance of the Display window.
The display screen has a timer on it (wonder if this needs moving to the controller??) the timer counts down for 5 minutes or whatever is set, but this needs to be the same on both displays. So if one starts and is at 4 minutes both windows should show 4 minutes (not one showing 4 and 1 showing 5).

***I NEED AN EXACT DUPLICATE OF THE DISPLAY WINDOW (2 x bwin) AND THE CONTROL PANEL NEEDS TO BE ABLE TO MODIFY BOTH THE WINDOWS AT THE SAME TIME. (Like a mirror of the first Display Window).***

I Want my Application to:

- Be Controlled from the Control Panel Window
- Open Multiple versions of the same Display Window
- Control Panel to update each Display Window **Identically**
- Have a timer that runs a clock down on each display window *(I have already worked how to run a clock down but not sure if it needs changing to be on control panel rather than display window)*

I am sure this is possible, but not quite sure how to get it working properly.

Hopefully I am making sense with the question. Any queries I will try my best to answer you. (NB, I am making a basic scoreboard to show on 2 monitors at each end of the court).

*PS.. (I messed up so my Application has the cool name of WPFApplication2... I know.. I know.. hehe)*

Thanks Mex.

Comment: You have to create a new instance of bwin using copy constructor to copy all the value to new instance. and then use show. Current code will make existing window come to foreground, that you created in constructor.

Comment: If you use MVVM approach you can share a ViewModel for both Views.

Comment: I'm searching how to do both these methods and then I will try and implement. Thanks for giving me something to look into :)